# Can iPhone NFC support Bank Card reading?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

Hi its actually about a doubt clarification. Currently i'm working on an iOS Swift project. Here i want to store users bank card details. Now the card number is entered manually. But what i want is, can our iPhone NFC reader can reads the bank cards(which have NFC) details through CoreNFC? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

it can/could but as I read it is not allowed. quoting docs:

"Important: Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs."

-- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc